# writing petgraph Dot to a file

Tags: rust, petgraph

I may be missing something very basic -- I am new to Rust.  I'm attempting to write a `petgraph::dot::Dot` representation to a file.

The following small code example doesn't compile:

```rust
use petgraph::Graph;
use petgraph::dot::{Dot, Config};
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;


fn main() {
    println!("hello graph!");
    let mut graph = Graph::<_, ()>::new();
    graph.add_node("A");
    graph.add_node("B");
    graph.add_node("C");
    graph.add_node("D");
    graph.extend_with_edges(&[
        (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3),
        (1, 2), (1, 3),
        (2, 3),
    ]);

    println!("{:?}", Dot::with_config(&graph, &[Config::EdgeNoLabel]));
    let mut f = File::create("example1.dot").unwrap();
    let output = format!("{}", Dot::with_config(&graph, &[Config::EdgeNoLabel]));
    f.write_all(&output.as_bytes());
}
```

Here's the compiler error output:

```
error[E0277]: `()` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> examples/graphviz.rs:21:32
   |
21 |     let output = format!("{}", Dot::with_config(&graph, &[Config::EdgeNoLabel]));
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Display` for `petgraph::dot::Dot<'_, &petgraph::graph_impl::Graph<&str, ()>>`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

The petgraph docs note that [Dot implements Display trait](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/petgraph/dot/struct.Dot.html#impl-Display) and I based my code on sample code in [trait.Display doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/fmt/trait.Display.html)

I can get the code to work by changing the format string to `{:?}` but I thought that was only supposed to be for debugging.  Is there a better way to write code to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dot` implements `Display` only if both the edge and node weights implement `Display`.

Since your edges are `()`, you cannot display this graph.

For example, changing the graph declaration to use `i32` edge weights:

```
    let mut graph = Graph::<_, i32>::new();
```

causes the program to compile with no errors.

Comment: thanks!  changing to `let mut graph = Graph::<_, i32>::new();` worked -- now I see where the docs refer to the edge/node implementation of Display